# Send a NSMutableArray to Json server in PHP

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, json, nsmutablearray

I have an NSmutableArray, and i want to send to the server in JSON format,the server will deserialize it and uptade the mysql.

```
NSMutableArray * jsonObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Some",nil];
NSString* jsonString = jsonObject.JSONRepresentation;
```

I think that´s the ideia its correct?
And how to send to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out NSMutableURLRequest's setHTTPMethod: (@"POST") and setHTTPBody: methods. You can build request and send it by NSURLConnection.

[NSMutableURLRequest class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[NSURLConnection class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Yes, search for an example of "POST" with URL request.  Most web services don't receive data in JSON, they return it in that format.  You send data to most http servers in a POST body format that looks like ugly formatted URL data `name=John&foo=bar&…`